# How to use coinbase API to convert BTC to ETH?

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am using coinbase API on python.

I know this is how I can buy BTC using fiat.

`buy = account.buy(amount='1',currency="BTC",payment_method=payment_method.id)`

But what if I want to convert my BTC to ETH?

Comment: What did you find in the documentation of coinbase about this?